# Matrix keypad of 8051 MCU not working

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

I use the MCU 8051 IDE and currently I am trying to work with the keypad in the emulator.

At first I set the Port/Bits for the specific keys but when I press a key the assigned bit(s) are not being set. I don't get any response if a key is pressed or not.

I checked the documentation but there is no further information which could help me.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Picture of the keypad:

[image: marix keypad]

As I can trace the memory in the emulator I do not need code.

Comment: Please post a minimal piece of code to demonstrate the issue (scanning just a single row of keys). When you say you _set_ bits for specific keys, I become a little suspicious; in the few keypad implementations I have seen in my life, you always had to _clear_ bits.

Comment: I edited my answer. The bits are cleared, I can see everything in the emulator and nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. Actually the bits are set but the emulator is buggy and does not show it in the GUI.